# Echo complete HTML source code

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to get source code of external URL and i got that working already but when i'm trying to output i see it stops reading the source code at some point.. I tried to replace < with < and > with > but maybe there is more i need to do?

Here is the PHP code after the Ajax call-

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $result) as $line){
    if (preg_match('/[A-Z]+[a-z]/', $line)) {
        $line = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $line);
        $line = str_replace('>', '&gt;', $line);
        echo $line;
    }
}
```

You can see here a [live example][1]
  [1]: http://checker.xcore.co.il/ Just enter your website address on top and you will see it stops reading the source at some point but until then it looks fine

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why not just use `htmlspecialchars()` around what you want to output?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't change much.. I tried it now after i made some modifications earlier and now it works thanks :)